# Video encoding for Android HTML5

Tags: android, html, video, html5-video, mp4

I have read lots of threads and articles all with pointers around how to encode video for HTML5 playback in Android.

No matter how much I try the various settings, using Handbrake or Miro, I still have trouble.

Case in point:

This video:
http://mediasvcp5lc0xlx242lz.blob.core.windows.net/baby/wf_android.mp4

works fine...

This video, encoded with exactly the same parameters:
http://mediasvcp5lc0xlx242lz.blob.core.windows.net/baby/Kia-1.mp4

..does not.

Can anybody point me at something definitive that will help me understand what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first video works beause it has been encoded with profile `Baseline`, while the second video has been encoded with profile `High`, as such does not play on Android devices.

They both are encoded at level 2.1 which is OK, but possibly excessive for the resolution and framerate you have. You can lower it down to level 2, if your encoder allows you to.

Try and encode the second video using profile `Baseline` as well, it should work.

Cheers,

Comment: Some follow-ups: How did you check this? What encoder supports Baseline? I don't see it in Handbrake or Miro.

Comment: Lot of tools out there, I just used http://gpac.sourceforge.net/ but there are others. Please note how both files were encoded using HandBrake 0.9.8 2012071700, so double check the encoding options. I do not use HandBrake myself so I cannot help. Post another question if you cannot fin your way.

Comment: Basically any encoder should support Baseline profile, check the documentation. You might have problems when encoding for low-level Apple decives (e.g. iPod) as they require a Constraint-baseline profile which is not too common.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try gpac. Oddly enough, I uploaded the non-working video to Windows Azure Media Services and re-encoded it there. The resultant version works, but the file size is 3.5x what it had been...still it's progress.

Comment: In Handbrake version 0.10.5.0, the "Baseline" option is under the "H.264 Profile" dropdown when using the H.264 video codec on the "Video" tab.